# List of dataframes to dataframe of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to convert a list of dataframes to a dataframe of lists? For example:

```
lst = [pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [10, 20]}),
       pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 4, 5], 'B': [30, 40, 50]})]
```

Expected result:

```
           A             B
0     [1, 2]      [10, 20]
1  [3, 4, 5]  [30, 40, 50]
```

My real list contains thousands of dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [10, 20]}),
       pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 4, 5], 'B': [30, 40, 50]})]

dic_lst = [df.to_dict(orient='list') for df in lst]

pd.DataFrame(dic_lst)
```

Comment: Don't know how efficient it's for thousands of dataframes... but it's the most straightforward solution I can think of.

Comment: Nice one. It should be quite fast ;)

Answer (score 2):

We could do

```
out = pd.concat(dict(enumerate(lst))).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
Out[1053]: 
           A             B
0     [1, 2]      [10, 20]
1  [3, 4, 5]  [30, 40, 50]
```